# How change to search algorithm for material ui datagrid quickfilter?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

I try to update `quickFilterParser` and `quickFilterFormatter` but they only change the `searchValue`. Is there a way to change search algorithm to add locale invariant search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching docs and default column definitions, I found there is `getApplyQuickFilterFn` props to change algorithm. [Doc link](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#custom-filtering-logic)

For example, edited default string filter to Locale based comparison for turkish

```js
const getGridStringQuickFilterFn = (value: any) => {
  if (!value) {
    return null;
  }
  const _val = value.toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
  const filterRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(_val), "i");
  return ({ value: columnValue }: GridCellParams): boolean => {
    return columnValue != null
      ? filterRegex.test(columnValue.toString().toLocaleLowerCase("tr"))
      : false;
  };
};
```

[image: Edit MUI X issue template (forked)]